# bash: read file path from another file and open with vim

Tags: bash, vim, scripting

Suppose I have following directory structure:

```
~/tmp$ ls edit.d/
1.t  2.t  3.t
```

and such a file:

```
~/tmp$ cat edit.list
edit.d/1.t
edit.d/2.t
edit.d/3.t
```

I would like to read the `edit.list` file line by line, each of which corresponds to path to one file in the directory shown above, and open up the file in vim. So far I have tried

```
while read line; do vim -o $line; done <edit.list
```

and

```
cat edit.list | while read line; do vim -o $line; done
```

but neither of them works. The error message returned is

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...

Vim: Finished.
```

I suspect this has something to do with vim's expectation of its stdin being the same as its controlling terminal, but not sure how to fix it.

This command

```
while read line; do cat $line | vim - ; done <edit.list
```

shows the file contents, but since it is piped in on `stdin`, the modifications can't be saved.

A terrible workaround is to use this command

```
while read line; do echo $line | vim - ; done <edit.list
```

to open vim with the file path as content and then to use `fg` or `<c-w>g` to open up the actual file to edit.

Is there a better solution, preferably being a one liner, to this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you redirect standard input for the loop, `vim` inherits that as its standard input as well. Use a different file descriptor instead.

```
while IFS= read -r <&3 line; do vim -o "$line"; done 3< edit.list
```

Now `vim` still uses the terminal for standard input, and while it also inherits file descriptor 3 from the `while` loop, it doesn't try to actually read from it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a loop. Command substitution does the job with less typing:

```
$ vim -o `< edit.list`
```

or:

```
$ vim -o $(< edit.list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've overridden the standard input to `vim`, not just that for the while loop. You can fix this by explicitly telling `vim` to take its standard input from the controlling terminal, `/dev/tty`:

```
while read line; do vim "$line" < /dev/tty; done < edit.list
```